# SQL error 4145 is thrown

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get all account holders with a positive closing balance. Only the last positive closing balance is interesting, so I want to have the Max Id of my table. I'm trying the following

```
SELECT DA.HOLDER, FAB.AMOUNT
    FROM ACCOUNTS_TABLE DA
        JOIN BALANCE_TABLE FAB ON FAB.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
    WHERE FAB.IS_CLOSING = 1 AND FAB.AMOUNT > 0
    GROUP BY DA.HOLDER
    HAVING MAX(FAB.DATE);
```

But when I try to execute this query, I get following error:

> Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where
>   a condition is expected, near ';'. SQLState:  S0001 ErrorCode: 4145

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to compare the value from `HAVING MAX(FAB.DATE)` to something, e.g.: `HAVING MAX(FAB.DATE) = current_date`

Comment: I want to have the last closing balance, how do I do that?

Comment: Try this `HAVING MAX(FAB.DATE) = select max(date) from BALANCE_TABLE`

Comment: Are you sure this should be tagged as Oracle? That doesn't look like an Oracle error!

Comment: @Utsav, than it's not grouped by the holder anymore

Comment: then do the requited join in the query. something like `HAVING MAX(FAB.DATE) = select max(fab.date) from BALANCE_TABLE fab join ........`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "greatest-n-per-group" question and they are typically solved with a window function:

```
SELECT holder, amount, fab_date
FROM (
  SELECT da.holder, 
         fab.amount, 
         fab.date as fab_date,
         max(fab.date) OVER (PARTITION BY da.holder) as max_date
  FROM accounts_table da
      JOIN balance_table fab ON fab.account_id = da.id
  WHERE fab.is_closing = 1 
    AND fab.amount > 0
)
WHERE fab_date = max_date;
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution but I get the following error: Error: ORA-00904: "FAB"."AMOUNT": invalid identifier

SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 904

Comment: @Guil: sorry, copy & paste error. The alias in the outer query is wrong. Corrected